# ionic 3 fcm.onNotification() error: class not found

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

When I executed this.fcm.onNotification() I have the error "Class not found".

I used an Android device.

I follow this documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/ and I don't know how resolve this problem

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    Node       : v10.6.0
    npm        : 6.1.0 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.4 Build version 9F1027a 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    constructor(private fcm: FCM) {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            alert('platform ready...');

            this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');

            this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
                alert(token);
                // backend.registerToken(token);
            });

            this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
                    if (data.wasTapped) {
                        alert("Received in background");
                    } else {
                        alert("Received in foreground");
                    }
                },
                error => alert(error)
            );

            this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
                alert(token);
                // backend.registerToken(token);
            });
 });
```

**Plugin version**

```
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
```

Comment: Try removing and re adding the library and the platform

Comment: are you testing on a real device? (cause this won't work via "ionic serve" approach).

Comment: Yes, I used with on a real device.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? I ran into it myself today..

Comment: I used this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/